# UNC vs Physical path on Windows

Tags: windows, security, unc

I develop Windows application that write data to file located on filesystem.
I have 2 options to reach the filesystem:

1. Physical path: C:\Folder\Myfile.txt
2. UNC Path (Configured RWX MyShare): \MyShare\Myfile.txt

When using Physical path we never get errors when handling the file.
When using UNC, Sometimes when handling the file, we receive "unexpected network error occurred".

I am wondering if UNC and Physical path is using different drivers/kernel modules/security layers internally in the OS?

On linux when you File.Open or File.Read, it depend on the filesystem type, each filesystem will have different implementation, you will go through different security layers. Is it the same on windows?

**Questions:**

1. When using UNC / Physical path, do we go via different drivers / seucity layers?
2. When Using UNC, Could it be Endpoint protection/Firewall/Antivirus might add **additional** security layer?

Comment: First, your UNC syntax is wrong. Second, please be precise about what "sometimes receive" mean - some computers, network down, etc.

Comment: Sorry the "\\' is due to StackExchange editing,  In Sometimes I mean sometimes UNC works fine And sometimes when using UNC we get "unexpected network error occurred", The data we write to disc is different each time, so my first suspect is that by using UNC, a 3rd party Antivirus/EDR/Internal Firewall is causing issues. We dont get any errors when using Physical path.

Comment: I think your suspicions have a good chance of being right. You may need to disable such software selectively and wait for errors. You could perhaps use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace all disk operations to the shares, but this might not give enough information to locate that software.

Comment: I assume going via UNC goes through some network stack/drivers and not regular disk I/O, whoever (EDR) listen to the network stack (even hooking to drivers) can cause delays/issues. I just dont know if the OS can recognize and optimize the bahavior of "If the UNC is same host -> Dont go via network stack"

Answer (score 0):

windows uses entirely different methods for addressing local and remote paths. this is evident by the [infamous](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=unexpected%20network%20error%20occurred) error message you receive.

windows will use the kernel filesystem APIs and drivers to address a locally attached disk, whereas unc paths use the SMB protocol to resolve system names, connect to shares, and perform operations like file IO. SMB presents semantics that sit atop a filesystem, such that the windows application doesn't know or care what kind of filesystem is in use. for instance accessing a Samba share on a linux system from windows works fine, even though windows does not know how to work a Ext4 filesytem. SMB does all the work of translating from actual disks, partitions, volumes, and files, to a generic interface.

Linux generally follows a different approach for network data. instead of performing adhoc connections, it puts the network filesystem protocol drivers under the mount, such that from an applications perspective all mounted locations are equally accessible. With the notable exception of [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), user-space processes don't know where a given mount point is actually pointing to. The downside to that is of course that you need to configure the OS to mount the network location in advance, before the application loads, and makes it difficult for applications to create their own network connections to remote filesystems.

Comment: Thank Frank, So In windows, when using UNC its on top of SMB and NOT as with physical path. If I close port 445 locally, will it work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will just guarantee "unexpected network errors".  so why are you trying to use network pathing when you seem to what to always eval the path via the local filesystem APIs? two weird tips I've learned when writing programs using network paths: always put a trailing backslash on a dir path, and always ensure that you close connections when done with them, even if another crash occurs while the connection is open (try... finally).

Comment: Because we support a network share, We'll make sure that if the path is physical, to use a physical path. thanks! so far, it was not supported (a Physical path)